# internet sharing not working

Tags: internet-sharing

Lumia phone internet sharing worked until I installed Nortons for 3 devices - when I tried to install on my mobile was advised Nortons won't work on Windows phone. Internet sharing worked perfectly previously.

Comment: Try uninstalling Norton, perhaps? Sounds like it's to blame.

Comment: How did you even get to try to install Norton?